# Forcing Jackson to deserialize specific property to specific primitive type

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

I'm using `jackson 2.9.6` I have a object that I want to serialize and Deserialize. Here is a class `Post`

**Post.java**

```
public class Post  extends GenericJson {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private int count;

    private List<Comment> commentList;

    // Getter and setter

}

public class Comment  extends GenericJson{

    private Long id;
    private String text;
    private int count;

    // Getter and setter

}
```

**JSON Data**

```
{
    "id" : 123,
    "name" : "azeem",
    "count" : 1,
    "commentList" : [
        {
            "id" : 312,
            "text" : "simple comment",
            "count" : 3
        },
        {
            "id" : 31221231231231,
            "text" : "simple comment 2",
            "count" : 1
        }
    ]
},

    "id" : 123127877186786,
    "name" : "arfan",
    "count" : 5,
    "commentList" : [
        {
            "id" : 312,
            "text" : "simple comment",
            "count" : 3
        },
        {
            "id" : 31221231231231,
            "text" : "simple comment 2",
            "count" : 1
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm using `ObjectMapper` to read and write, like this.

**For Write**

```
 objectMapper.writeValue(fileDir, postObject);
```

**For Read**

```
 objectMapper.readValue(savedFileDir, Post.class); // Error can't cast int to long
```

As you can see there is error **can't cast int to long post['id']** and same in `commentList` this is because in **Json Data** first `id` is **123** So `jackson` consider it as `int` and try to save it on `Long id`

I see an answer on **StackOverFlow** that use `DeserializationFeature.USE_LONG_FOR_INTS` But I can't use it because there is another property `count` which I need it in `int`.

If I use `DeserializationFeature.USE_LONG_FOR_INTS` it show me error that **Long can't cast to int post['count']** and same as `commentList`

I want to ask that Is there any way I can convert specific property to  specific primitive type. For example in this I want `id` property always in `Long` in both `Post` and `Comment`. Other all properties are fine.

Can you please let me know how can I do that.

**Update**

`Post` and `Comment` class is auto generate and can't make any changes in these files. Actually I'm using **Google cloud endpoints v2** these files are
generated by **cloud endpoint**. Cloud endpoints use the same `jackson` lib to convert json data into these class object but I don't know they do it.

Comment: Does `id` need to be the wrapper type? Can you change it to the primitive `long`?

Comment: I can't make any changes in these files, I update my question please check it

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@JsonSetter` to solve this problem.

```
public class Post {

private Long id;
private String name;
private int count;

private List<Comment> commentList;

// Getter and setter


@JsonSetter
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = (long) id;
}
}
```

One problem in your json. `,` missing.

> "count" : 1
>
> "count" : 5

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention these files are auto generated and I can't make any changes into it. I update my question please check it.

Comment: is your json valid? i see there is missing `,`

Comment: even can not reproduce your problem. Your code working fine without set '@JsonSetter`

Comment: Ohh, I check the Class definition these classes are extended from  `GenericJson` maybe this is creating problem Because this code is not working for me. And I also update the Json data to remove these errors